# Moving a rectangle in Swing JPanel: original stays

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to make a tower of hanoi solver which simply solves the hanoi without any mouse events. The problem is when I move the rectangle the original remains, even after I repaint. I've searched the net and tried changing the code around but nonthing worked. I am using a JFrame with a JPanel inside of it if that changes anything.
I have my disk class here which is just a rectangle with colour.

```
class Disk extends Rectangle {

    Color diskColour;

    public Disk(int a, int b, int c, int d, Color colour) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        width = c;
        height = d;
        diskColour = colour;
    }

    public Color getColour() {
        return diskColour;
    }

    public void paintSquare(Graphics g) {
        repaint();
        g.setColor(diskColour);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();


    }
}
```

Here is my code where I actually call the paintSquare method:

```
    public void simpleMoveDisk(Disk[] disks, int n, Graphics g) {

    disks[n].setLocation(30,25);
    disks[n].paintSquare(g);
    repaint();

}
```

The paintSquare method paints the disk, while the setLocation method changes its coordinates.
When this runs the rectangle occurs in the new location, however the old one still remains. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling repaint() in several places and you shouldn't be.

Have your the top level class that is doing the painting, call the paintSquare method and any other method that is needed.   Those methods should not be calling repaint().

Also your simple move disk is really strange in the fact that it passes an array of Disks, an index, and a graphics object.  Instead make it just take in a Disk.  Just pass it the one out of the array that is needed to be updated.  Then let whatever class that calls simpleMoveDisk, separately make a call to repaint instead of trying to paint and update the model in the same method.

Comment: Thanks for the A. I've changed the code according to your answer, the rectangle still stays. 
`public void simpleMoveDisk(Disk disks) {
        moves++;
        disks.setLocation(20, 30);
    }`

Comment: You need to post an SSCCE then.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have found the problem. It was because my initDisk method, which initializes the disks position, was being called more than once. it repaints the disks in their original position even though one has been moved. After ensuring it only ran once, the original disappeared.